# Probability mass function of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, summation, fractions

Let $\mathbb P(L=k) = \frac{140}{223(k+2)}, k = 0, 1, ..., 5.$

Credit portfolio consists of 8 *independent* loans, where $L_i, i = 1, ..., 8$ is the number of “physically” possible defaults of one loan. $L_i$ hasthe same distribution as $L$.

Let $L_{PF}=L_1+...+L_8.$ Find pmf: $G_{L_{PF}}(t)$.

**I started from:**
$G_{L_{PF}}(t) = \mathbb Et^{L_{PF}}=\mathbb Et^{L_1+...+L_8}=\prod_{i=1}^{8} \mathbb Et^{L_i}=\prod_{i=1}^{8} G_{L_i}(t)$

Then

$G_{L_i}(t) = \mathbb Et^{L_i}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k \mathbb P(L_i=k)=\frac{140}{223}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k+2} $

How to continue? How can I get pmf of $G_{L_{PF}}(t)$?

Comment: Isn´t it $\prod\limits_{\color{red}t=1}^{8} G_{L_i}(t)$?

Comment: I think, it is not.

Comment: In your expression for $G_{L_i}(t)$ you have a finite sum from k=0 to 5. To find $G_{L_{PF}}(t)$, you need to raise that to the power of 8 since all $L_i$'s have the same distribution. Finally you can get the pmf by reading off the coefficients of $t^k$. It's all a bit cumbersome, but I suppose it can be done.

Comment: @Lucyy OK. I just wanted to prevent possible typos or misunderstandings.

Comment: @Lucyy Due your comment I´ve posted another answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Can you help me with one similar short question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267626/probability-mass-function-of-sum-of-independent-random-variables-l-i

Comment: @Lucyy Not at the moment. But this isn´t a problem since there are many other good mathematicians here on MSE. Maybe you have wait a few hours for a good answer to that questions, but this shouldn´t be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait, if no one will help me earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that $\ln(1-x)=-\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^m}{m} $ (series expansion at $x=0$).

$$-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k+2}\stackrel{m=k+2}{=}-\frac1{t^2}\cdot \sum\limits_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{m}=\frac1{t^2}\cdot \left( \ln(1-t)+t \right)$$

Therefore $G_{L_i}(t)=\frac{140}{223}\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k+2}=-\frac{140}{223}\cdot\frac{\ln(1-t)+t}{t^2}$

Now it is straightforward to calculate $G_{L_{PF}}(t) $.